# Combine AND and OR Operators in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I Would like to combine an AND and an OR operation in one Regex.

I do have 2 sets of tags. Set A and Set B. Within a set i need an OR operation and between Sets an AND.

Example:

```
Set A has 3 values:
A1, A2, A3
Set B has 2 values:
B1 and B2
```

Example search operations:

```
A1 OR A2 AND B2
A2 OR A3 AND B1 OR B2
...
```

Any idea how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Within a set i need an OR operation and between Sets an AND.

You can use lookahead like this:

```
^(?=.*?(?:A1|A2|A3))(?=.*?(?:B1|B2)).*$
```

**Description:**

```
(?=.*?(?:A1|A2|A3)) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
(?:A1|A2|A3) Non-capturing group
1st Alternative: (null, matches any position)
2nd Alternative: A1
A1 matches the characters A1 literally (case sensitive)
3rd Alternative: A2
A2 matches the characters A2 literally (case sensitive)
4th Alternative: A3
A3 matches the characters A3 literally (case sensitive)
(?=.*?(?:B1|B2)) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
(?:B1|B2) Non-capturing group
1st Alternative: (null, matches any position)
2nd Alternative: B1
B1 matches the characters B1 literally (case sensitive)
3rd Alternative: B2
B2 matches the characters B2 literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: Will match `"A1 B1"`, against OP's spec.

Comment: There are some contradictions in the question. It also says `Within a set i need an OR operation and between Sets an AND` and as per that spec `A1 and B1` is right match.

Comment: `"A1 AND B1"` might be correct. `"A1 B1"` is not. There should be an operator between each element (with the restriction that there is never an `"OR"` between elements of different sets).

Comment: You mean we have to match literal string `"AND"` also?

Comment: Look at the example search operations. I strongly suspect "yes". (I edited to format as code; they were in separate rows in source, but markdown pasted them together when they were considered text.)

Comment: Too be honest I am not 100% sure if those are search strings. Question says `search operations`. I will request OP to clarify and provide some concrete examples.

Comment: Here is a concrete example:
Set 1 has Country ISO Codes (US, FR, CN etc)
Set 2 has Job Functions (AA = Controlling, BB = Human Resources etc)

Now i would like to search for any Job in US or FR with the function AA. So its a "US or FR and AA" search operation

Comment: In that case regex would be on similar lines as I posted i.e. **`^(?=.*?(?:US|FR))(?=.*?AA).*$`**

Answer (score 0):

I will submit that Regexps are a wrong tool here. You want a parser. Or, more simply, split your string by `"AND"`, then for each element, split by `"OR"`, and check that all the tags are in the same set.